# Issue Displaying Multiple Beacons in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ibeacon

I am trying to display multiple beacons in a tableView. The minor values, name, and images for each beacon are stored in core data. While the name and image of the beacon are appearing in the tableView cell correctly, the proximity always changing to the closest beacon.

I really appreciate the help!

```
DisplayTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID"];
Tag *tag = [self.tags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = @"";    

NSData *data = tag.image;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image = image; //BEACONS

if (self.tags.count > 0)
{        
    self.arrow.hidden = true;
    self.addLabel.hidden = true;    

    CLBeacon *beacon = [self.beacons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *proximityLabel = @"";
    switch (beacon.proximity)
    {
        case CLProximityFar:
            proximityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your %@ is Far", tag.name];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(107/255.0) blue:(105/255.0) alpha:1];
            break;        
        case CLProximityNear:
            proximityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your %@ is Near", tag.name];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(96/255.0) green:(102/255.0) blue:(232/255.0) alpha:1];
            break;
        case CLProximityImmediate:
            proximityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your %@ is Close", tag.name];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(118/255.0) green:(225/255.0) blue:(167/255.0) alpha:1];
            break;            
        case CLProximityUnknown:
            proximityLabel = @"Fetching Location";
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            break;
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = tag.name;    

    NSString *detailLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Dist: %0.001f", proximityLabel, beacon.accuracy];
    cell.proxLabel.text = detailLabel;        

    self.tableView.hidden = false;
    self.mapView.hidden = false;
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that every row shows the same value of detailLabel?  Perhaps it has something to do with the setup of your prototype cell.